# pwntools' p32 function is weird

Tags: python, pack, unpack, pwntools

I'm testing on Intel x86_64, Ubuntu 64bit, Python3, Pwntools v4.3.1

```
$ python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pwn import *
>>> addr = 0xbffffb78
>>> print(p32(addr))
b'x\xfb\xff\xbf'
```

In my opinion, the correct packing result for `0xbffffb78` should be`\x78\xfb\xff\xbf`.

But why did `b'x\xfb\xff\xbf`' happen?
where is \x78 ?

And what is the correct way of packing, not using `p32()`?

Answer (score 3):

This is just how Python renders [bytes objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typebytes). If a byte can be rendered as an ASCII character, it is displayed as one.

```
>>> b"\x78"
b'x'
```

To see the bytes rendered as hex you can use the [hex method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex) of the bytes object:

```
>>> b'x\xfb\xff\xbf'.hex()
'78fbffbf'
```

Comment: i See. Is it just a matter of printed output? Does the actual data still remain as \x78?

Comment: @CPUU I've added some info about displaying bytes as hex to my answer.